# How do I change the value of a checkbox in a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have appended a column of checkboxes to a DataGridView using the following:

```
Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, chk)
```

How do I change the checked state of a particular checkbox?

I have tried using the following code:

```
Dim val2 As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DataGridView1.Item(243, i)
val2.Value = True
DataGridView1.Item(243, i) = val2
```

The last line resulted in runtime error "InvalidOperationException was Unhandled
Cell provided already belong to a grid". Index 243 exists.

Answer (score 2):

The last line is actually unneeded. Just do:

```
Dim val2 As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DataGridView1.Item(243, i)
val2.Value = True
```

val2 keeps a reference of the DataGridView's Cell. If you change its Value property, this change will be reflected in the user interface.

A simpler way of doing this would be:

```
DataGridView1.Item(243, i).Value = True
```

But it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that good with VB.NET but here's the C# syntax:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = true;
```

Comment: VB is the same, just use parenthesis instead of brackets and remove the ;